# MP4 streaming in FireFox but not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, http-headers, audio-streaming

I'm building a Node.js program and I've gotten a fairly good music streaming method down. But for some reason, the audio is only streaming in FireFox (not in Chrome). I've provided a sample link for a song I know isn't working here. I'm almost positive this is a header issue. What should I change to get everything working smoothly?

Note: If the above url says "No App Running" or something along those lines, wait about an hour and try again. I'm currently knee-deep in development.

Two requests are made by Chrome:

```
GET https://mesh-c9-triforce1.c9.io/stream/Katrah-Query/Rainfall%20Roots HTTP/1.1
Host: mesh-c9-triforce1.c9.io
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: https://mesh-c9-triforce1.c9.io/stream/Katrah-Query/Rainfall%20Roots
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Range: bytes=0-
```

And:

```
GET https://mesh-c9-triforce1.c9.io/stream/Katrah-Query/Rainfall%20Roots HTTP/1.1
Host: mesh-c9-triforce1.c9.io
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: https://mesh-c9-triforce1.c9.io/stream/Katrah-Query/Rainfall%20Roots
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Range: bytes=2808-
```

The response headers are the same for both:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
last-modified: Wed, 12 Mar 2014 08:56:38 GMT
date: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 23:40:14 GMT
expires: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 23:40:14 GMT
content-type: audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 4754197
```

Comment: Nothing is working for me at that URL.  A connection is made, request is sent, but there are zero bytes being sent as the response.  You need to post a complete question on Stack Overflow.  Otherwise, your question is useless to those who come by later on.  If you think there is some sort of header issue, then run a packet capture and post the request and response data in your question so we can look at it.  It's probably going to come down to a codec issue if I had to guess.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've fixed the application and it should be giving a response now. What more should I add to my question? I have no more information.

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=387604

Comment: Also, it looks like your content length header has an incorrect value.

Comment: Thanks! That question actually looks way better. I figure the best (and easiest) thing to do from here would just be to wait until the bug is fixed.